# Getting JSON on PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

This is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM .....";
$exe = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$return_arr = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exe)) {
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
```

I try to use `json_encode($return_arr);` and the result showed : `[{'me', 'you'},{'we','they'}]`
but i need data array, that showing like this : `{Data = [{'me', 'you'},{'we','they'}]};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change the `json_encode`.

- From:

  > `json_encode($return_arr);`
- To:

  > `json_encode(['data' => $return_arr])`;

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `json_decode`, not `json_encode`.

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) returns a string, from a variable.

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) returns a variable, from a string.